# Error 404 Not Found when I am using Tomcat WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, java-ee-6, tomcat9

I am working on a project in *Tomcat*. I am using *Java EE* and recently added a *WebSocket* to a project and created a simple chat with it. Locally everything worked fine but when I created the *WAR* file and launched the application with it, the *WebSocket* part of the project causes the following error:

[image]

I am using 9.0.38 *Tomcat* version.

Apart from this one problem, the whole app works fine.

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's look like your *Websocket* dependency in your *pom.xml* file?

The scope of *WebSocket* dependency must be `provided` if already isn't:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used dependency javax.websocket, but it turned out that the problem was only with my Mozilla Firefox browser. If someone also had this problem, I recommend checking it on Chrome or Edge because it worked for me.

I still don't know what the problem with Firefox is, but in my case I don't have to solve it - it's important that it works on other browsers.

Thank you Mehdi Rahimi for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).